# Time Series: Fill NaNs from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, temperature

I am working with temperature data and I have created a file that has multi-year averages of few thousand cities and the format is as below(`df1`)

```
Date    City    PRCP    TMAX    TMIN    TAVG
01-Jan  Zurich  0.94    3.54    0.36    1.95
01-Feb  Zurich  4.12    9.14    3.04    6.09
01-Mar  Zurich  4.1     5.9     0.3     3.1
01-Apr  Zurich  0.32    13.78   4.22    9
01-May  Zurich  9.42    11.32   5.34    8.33
.
.
.....
```

I have the above data for all 365 days with no nulls. Notice that the `date` column only has `day` and `month` because year is irrelevant.

Based on the above data I am trying to clean yearly files, my second dataframe has data in the below format(`df2`)

```
ID      Date        City    PRCP    TAVG    TMAX    TMIN
abcd1   2020-01-01  Zurich  0       -1.9    -0.9    
abcd1   2020-01-02  Zurich  9.1             12.7    4.9
abcd1   2020-01-03  Zurich  0.8      8.55   13.2    3.9
abcd1   2020-01-04  Zurich  0        4.1    10.8    -2.6

.
.
.....
```

Each city has a unique `ID`. The date column has the format `%y-%m-%d`.

I am trying to replace the nulls in the second dataframe with the values in my first dataframe by matching `day` and `month`. This is what I tried

```
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"], errors = 'coerce')   ##date format change##
df1["Date"] = df1['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m')
df2 = df2.drop(columns='ID')

df2 = df2.fillna(df1)         ##To replace nulls##

df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"], errors = 'coerce')
df1["Date"] = df1['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')      ## Change data back to original format##
```

Even with this I end up with nulls in my yearly file i.e. `df2`{Note: df1 has no nulls}

Please suggest a better way to replace only nulls or any corrections to the code if necessary.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but df1 has no nulls so you meant `df2 = df1.fillna(df2) `?

Comment: Unrelated to getting Pandas to spit out what you want for NaNs, but related to the question of "is there a better way to replace nulls," you might want to look at Sklearn. They have a few built-in tools for imputing missing values: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes that's what I meant, sorry for the typo

Comment: Let me know if any further clarification on the answer required!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can approach by adding a column `Date2` onto `df2` with the same format as the `Date` column on `df1`.  Then, while setting both dataframes with this date format and City as index, we perform an update on df2 using [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), as follows:

```
df2["Date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date"], errors = 'coerce').dt.strftime('%d-%b')          #  dd-MMM (e.g. 01-JAN)

df2a = df2.set_index(['Date2', 'City'])        # Create df2a from df2 with set index on Date2 and City

df2a.update(df1.set_index(['Date', 'City']), overwrite=False)   # update only NaN values of df2a by corresponding values of df1

df2 = df2a.reset_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)    # result put back to df2 throwing away the temp `Date2` row index

df2.insert(2, 'City', df2.pop('City'))    # relocate column City back to its original position
```

[`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) is to modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.  The DataFrame’s length does not increase as a result of the update, only values at matching index/column labels are updated. Hence, we make both dataframe with same row index so that updates will be performed on corresponding columns with same column index/labels.

Note that we use the parameter `overwrite=False` in [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) to ensure we only update values that are NaN in the original DataFrame `df2`.

### Demo

**Data Setup:**

Added data onto `df1` to showcase replacing values of `df2` from `df1`:

```
print(df1)

     Date    City  PRCP   TMAX  TMIN  TAVG
0  01-Jan  Zurich  0.94   3.54  0.36  1.95
1  02-Jan  Zurich  0.95   3.55  0.37  1.96       <=== Added this row
2  01-Feb  Zurich  4.12   9.14  3.04  6.09
3  01-Mar  Zurich  4.10   5.90  0.30  3.10
4  01-Apr  Zurich  0.32  13.78  4.22  9.00
5  01-May  Zurich  9.42  11.32  5.34  8.33

print(df2)       #  before processing

      ID        Date    City  PRCP  TAVG  TMAX  TMIN
0  abcd1  2020-01-01  Zurich   0.0 -1.90  -0.9   NaN         <=== with NaN value
1  abcd1  2020-01-02  Zurich   9.1   NaN  12.7   4.9         <=== with NaN value
2  abcd1  2020-01-03  Zurich   0.8  8.55  13.2   3.9
3  abcd1  2020-01-04  Zurich   0.0  4.10  10.8  -2.6
```

**Run new codes:**

```
df2["Date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Date"], errors = 'coerce').dt.strftime('%d-%b')          #  dd-MMM (e.g. 01-JAN)

df2a = df2.set_index(['Date2', 'City'])        # Create df2a from df2 with set index on Date2 and City

df2a.update(df1.set_index(['Date', 'City']), overwrite=False)   # update only NaN values of df2a by corresponding values of df1

df2 = df2a.reset_index(level=1).reset_index(drop=True)    # result put back to df2 throwing away the temp `Date2` row index

df2.insert(2, 'City', df2.pop('City'))    # relocate column City back to its original position
```

**Result:**

```
print(df2)


      ID       Date    City  PRCP  TAVG  TMAX  TMIN
0  abcd1 2020-01-01  Zurich   0.0 -1.90  -0.9  0.36     <== TMIN updated with df1 value
1  abcd1 2020-01-02  Zurich   9.1  1.96  12.7  4.90     <== TAVG updated with df1 value
2  abcd1 2020-01-03  Zurich   0.8  8.55  13.2  3.90
3  abcd1 2020-01-04  Zurich   0.0  4.10  10.8 -2.60
```